# Open save data from txt where is dict and update and again save

Tags: python, tkinter, load, fwrite

How can I load data from a .txt file in which there are saved dictionaries from 14 sports(14 different dictionaries)? I need to edit and save the entries.

I currently save the program like this:

```
def ulozit():
    vsetko = (medicimbal.items(),zhyb.items(),zhybyChalani.items(),clnkovyb.items(), stoM.items(), tisicM.items(),tritisicM.items(), hodG.items(),skokdoD.items()
              ,sedL.items(),veslp.items(),kluk.items(),preskok.items(),skokdoD.items())
    f = open("vsetko.txt", "w")
    f.write( str(vsetko) )
    f.close()
```

I need to read and update the above, but how?

My program https://github.com/smajdalf89/Programovanie/edit/master/Tv%20Program start on line 464 as "def ulozit()".

In txt saved like below, the fields are name, which class, gender and exercise:

> (dict_items([('michal', ['1.a', 'CH', 9.0])]), dict_items([('danka',
>   ['2.a', 35.0])]), dict_items([('jozko', ['3.a', 30.0])]),
>   dict_items([('marian', ['4.a', 'ch', 6.0])]), dict_items([('martin',
>   ['3.a', 'Ch', 6.0])]), dict_items([('erik', ['1.b', 'CH', 3.05])]),
>   dict_items([('trulo', ['2.c', 'CH', 12.08])]), dict_items([('richard',
>   ['1.a', 'Ch', 30.0])]), dict_items([('michal', ['4.a', 'CH',
>   250.0])]), dict_items([('michal', ['4.a', 'CH', 250.0])]), dict_items([('jebo', ['3.d', 'CH', 9.0])]), dict_items([('michal',
>   ['2.a', 'CH', 1.2])]), dict_items([('milan', ['3.c', 'CH', 50.0])]),
>   dict_items([('lukas', ['1.c', 'CH', 25.0])]))

Comment: Better to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to save and load the dicts.

Comment: ok but how i can get all 14 dict in one ? @acw1668

Comment: Do you mean to save the 14 dicts into one file?

Comment: yes.. its sport program for teacher and every single sport have own dict(if you have time look link on github) and all what i record to dict want save and then open to get new record to update dict. I try now pickel but its problem to get all 14 dict to one. when i get like vsetko: {medicimlbal.items(),skokdodialky.items().....) get error like unhashable type: 'dict_items" @acw1668

Comment: Try `vsetko = (medicimbal, zhyb, ...)` (without `.items()`).  Then `with open('vsetko.pickle', 'wb') as f: pickle.dump(vsetko, f, protocol=-1)`.

Comment: its save something but now how to load? i have this `with open ('vsetko.pickle', 'rb') as f: vsetko =pickle.load(f)` but dont go @acw1668

Comment: `with open('vsetko.pickle', 'rb') as f: (medicimbal, zhyb, zhybyChalani, clnkovyb, stoM, tisicM, tritisicM, hodG, skokdoD, sedL, veslp, kluk, preskok, skokdoD) = pickle.load(f)`.

Comment: Note that you have two `skokodoD` in `vsetko`.

Comment: i repair last what you wrote. It s load but ist problem like this `File "C:/Users/micha/PycharmProjects/TV program/TV PROGRAM.py", line 199, in statistikaskokdodialky
    sko += f'{key.capitalize()}:{value}\n'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'capitalize'`  this show when i want see in statistic what is saved

Comment: its when i all stastic... the `sko` += f' is deffirent in all dict @acw1668

Comment: the problem is from other ...forget it, but `with open('vsetko.pickle', 'rb') as f: (medicimbal, zhyb, zhybyChalani, clnkovyb, stoM, tisicM, tritisicM, hodG, skokdoD, sedL, veslp, kluk, preskok, skokdoD) = pickle.load(f)` dont work, in pycharm is gray color thats the program don t know what is it

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/m76wkGVg) is an example on saving/loading pickle file.

Comment: If you prefer to use text file in case you want to change the values in the text file directly, you can use JSON format.  [Here](https://pastebin.com/EMXAACSg) is an example on saving/loading JSON file.

Comment: hi. i try but now don t save nothint and load nothing..i know that i want to much from you but can you try in my program? can by download from github in top . J son dont try because i thing will be the same problem. I try like this but i thing that problem 1 is i use all in tkinter and second get load dict information and get in back where must be.. [link](https://imgur.com/a/yaH4t3G)

Comment: program is simple.. i use tkinter for human friendly ..Hlavne menu is MAIN MENU, discipliny vkladanie dat is Sport disciplin - insert data....1. is NAME,2.which Class,3.CH-Boy,D-Girls and 4 is how done exercise-result.......Statistika is what i insert in sport to see and compare whos is best in class

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/eY9gGmr6) is a modified TV Program.

Comment: man you are GOD...thanks.......can i give a star or something to help you....thanks thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I just use text files for saving data atm.

For dictionaries, I store them like a CSV, where i use the split() function for key and values

For accessing the data, I use

```
    with open(filename, "r") as txtr:
        data = txtr.read()
```

after that I split the data multiple times and assign them to dictionaries.

To update the file, you would need to rewrite the whole text file. So 2 functions, save and load.